# Sum of subsets of N i.i.d Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

suppose we have subsets $I_1,I_2 \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ of size $n_1,n_2 <= n$ of n i.i.d Bernoulli trials $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and let $Y=\sum_{i \in I_1}X_i, Z=\sum_{i \in I_2}X_i$.

Any ideas on how to calculate

$\mathbb{P}(\{Y\leq k\}\cap\{Z\leq k\})$ in terms of the distribution of sums of  some $X_i$ for some $k\leq n$?

I assume it will be useful to describe
$Y = C + \tilde Y$ and $Z = C + \tilde Z$, where

$C = \sum_{i \in I_1 \cap I_2} X_i$

since then $C, \tilde Y, \tilde Z$ are independent.

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: HINT: one way to proceed is to condition on $C=c$ and use Law of Total Probability

Comment: yes, apparently you end up with $\sum_{c=0}^{|I_1 \cap I_2|} \mathbb{P}(Y\leq k - c)\mathbb{P}(Z\leq k)\mathbb{P}(C=c)...But maybe anyone can deduce a simpler form?